# Data Recovery Tool to recover lost Chrome User Data Dirs

Tags: backup, hardware, google-chrome, recovery, data-recovery

I have a folder, either  </users/an/downloads/user data> or  </users/an/downloads/user datas>, that I've accidentally cmd-opt-deleted.

The folder is used to store individual user data directories (used by Mac Chrome's `--user-data-dir` flag) and there are  **many** of such user directories. Collectively, there's a **huge trove of important information** within the deleted folder.

I'm willing to go to *any length* to recover the data. (I will exchange thousands of bucks to get back the data if needed, no-questions-asked.)

Is there a recovery tool that is able to recover this data? I've tried:

- Stellar Phoenix; [StellarPhoenixMacDataRecovery-Professional.dmg.zip](http://download.stellarinfo.com/StellarPhoenixMacDataRecovery-Professional.dmg.zip?_ga=2.62667752.51552499.1519257106-304165321.1519257106)
- Data Rescue; [Data_Rescue_5.0.4SR1.dmg](https://downloads.prosofteng.com/dr/Data_Rescue_5.0.4SR1.dmg)
- On Track Easy Recovery Mac; [OntrackEasyRecoveryMac.dmg](http://download.ontrack.com/freedownloads/ER_MAC_ENGLISH.zip) (Apple SG recommended this company for data recovery, yet when I phoned them, they claimed there's nothing they can do if their app can't see the data)

None of which is able to recover the data. 
**Is there a recovery tool specific to recovering Mac Chrome's user data dir?**

---

<sub>(default MacbookPro 15-inch 2017, macOS Sierra v10.12.5, 3.1 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3)
(APPLE SSD SM1024L Media—1 TB PCI-Express Internal Physical Disk, Macintosh HD—999.25 GB Logical Volume Mac OS Extended Journaled Encrypted)
(TimeMachine's [not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YvNf.png) on; FileVault's On)</sub>

Comment: If data rescue can’t find the files and you don’t have a backup, it’s looking very unhopeful other than paying for a forensic reconstruction and the data hasn’t been over written.

Comment: @bmike, Btw do you know at the moment what I **must not** do to reduce the probability that the data is over written? Also are there some "default Mac OS apps and utilities" that I must quickly **switch off** and stop them from auto-running by themselves such that they wouldn't run and accidentally override the data?

Comment: `... do you know at the moment what I must not do to reduce the probability that the data is over written?` - Yes. Stop using that drive immediately. If you did continue to use the drive in read/write mode (normal use) for any amount of time, the chance of data loss increased the longer you used it. I hope you realize this.

Comment: Yes. Power off immediately / don’t save and only connect to a forensic dock / write blocked connector if you can to attempt data recovery. Certainly install no update or apps or run anything else from that OS.

Comment: @bmike, IconDaemon. Right.. guess I didn't realized the extent of my situation then. Perhaps Windows have trained me to think that shift-dels are nothing to worry about.. verily I must regret buying a mac now, it's just a fking folder deletion and none can be done about it omg. The other day when I read your comment I immediately powerbutton-offed the laptop and made a full disk clone. ([Apple sure makes it as hard as possible to do so.](https://goo.gl/6YQfDh)). Hopefully it's not too late... I had been using the laptop for quite some time after the folder deletion.

Comment: Do you have a time machine backup?

Comment: @MelvinJefferson, Regrettably it's not on.

Comment: What does that file/folder hold? Is it something that can be saved in Chrome via logging in to the Google account?

Comment: @MelvinJefferson, **Records.** (You might think of every tab as a notepad. Indeed some of them are literally online anonymous notepads at alphanumeric-generated URLs. Probably a total of 3000 tabs across the multiple user data folders, with each averaging 20 pages of "foward / back" data. So that's ~60k urls with a `History` total of probably ~120k urls. The main archive is stored in a separate location but this archive itself is important and contains 6 months of data.) ..

Comment: ..Do you know if they are retrievable in any way? ¶ Each session is logon to Gmail, but not logon to that "start page" which asks you to login. That online webpage Google-Search-History seems to only show what you search on google and what you click on those search pages... hardly useful. ¶ I frankly only need the `History`, bookmarks, `Current Session`(?) / `Current Tabs` of each user-data-dir, but hunting through multiple "data recovery" software still turns up nothing.

Comment: That should be saved on the google account that you have signed into.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson, Are you serious? How can they be retrieved? ¶ Just then, I opened a brand new Chrome, and tried logging Chrome into one of the Google Account: **1**) https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2MCO.png **2**) https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSZqT.png **3**) https://i.stack.imgur.com/amWFg.png **4**) https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI7QC.png , but nothing happens. I don't think it works because for those lost user data dirs, those Chromes weren't on-synced. If I try to enable sync only now, it can't get back the past data.. just as with Time Machine I guess.